# Unable to wrap emails in one cell of the table using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs, I have created Group table and I'm facing problem while saving emails in members row, I mean when I add more than one email then the `members`row field is getting extended and `Action`
the field is going far away. Even when I apply JSON data also. When we use JSON... We can't figure which group is having maximum members' emails, so that's why I need to wrap the member field, which should show only one email and proceed with ... Symbol. Ex: in group 1 we have 3 emails, there we should get abc@yahoo.com... ( which should not exceed members row field)

Here is the code sample:

```
<Table>
            <Table.Header>
              <Table.Row>

                <Table.HeaderCell>Group Name</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell>Members</Table.HeaderCell>
                <Table.HeaderCell>Action</Table.HeaderCell>
              </Table.Row>
            </Table.Header>
            <Table.Body>

                <Table.Row >

                  <Table.Cell>Group 1</Table.Cell>
                  <Table.Cell >abc@yahoo.com, def@gmail.com, xyz@hotmail.com</Table.Cell>
                   <Table.Cell>
                    <Button variant="info">Edit</Button>
                    &nbsp;<Button variant="danger">Delete</Button>
                  </Table.Cell> 
                </Table.Row>
            </Table.Body>
          </Table>
```

Something in this way:

```
 manageEmails = (text) => {
    return text.slice(0, 26) + (text.length > 15 ? "..." : "");
  }
```

I couldn't able to figure out how to implement it in my table. Can anyone help me in this query
Here is the sample working one:

"https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-sun-bchh8"

Can anyone help me in this query in order to wrap within members fields (every field should have equal distance)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `fixed`

```
<Table fixed>
```

you can also try this

```
    <Table>
      <Table.Header>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.HeaderCell collapsing>Group Name</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Members</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell collapsing width={"4"}>Action</Table.HeaderCell>
        </Table.Row>
      </Table.Header>
      <Table.Body>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell collapsing>Group 1</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>
            abc@yahoo.com, def@gmail.com, xyz@hotmail.com
          </Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>
            <Button variant="info">Edit</Button>
            &nbsp;<Button variant="danger">Delete</Button>
          </Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.Cell>Group 2</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>abc@yahoo.com</Table.Cell>
          <Table.Cell>
            <Button variant="info">Edit</Button>
            &nbsp;<Button variant="danger">Delete</Button>
          </Table.Cell>
        </Table.Row>
      </Table.Body>
    </Table>
```

Comment: kayimbasioglu - if I have 50 members in group 10 then does this work in that situation also? When we use json... We can't figure which group is having maximum members emails, so that's why I need to wrap member field, which should show only one email and proceeded with ... Symbol. Ex: in group 1 we have 3 emails, there we should get `abc@yahoo.com...` ( which should not exceed members row field)

Comment: you need to tell us what you want to see. nobody can help you if you don't provide us what you (exactly) want to see as a result

Comment: Kayimbasioglu - I apologize for not posting appropraitely